# SQL Developer bind variables prompt: force string values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use SQL Developer bind variables prompt to speed up query execution, but I'm not getting the desired output: looks like the values I put in get converted in number.

Table description:

```
Nome               Null     Type         
------------------ -------- ------------ 
NUM                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(13) 
IS_OK                       NUMBER(1)
```

initial situation:

[image]

```
select NUM, IS_OK from numbers_table where NUM = cast(:dn as varchar2(13));

NUM         |IS_OK |
------------|------|
08331930078 |1     |
```

**working** updates:

1.

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = 08331930078;
```

2. 

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = '08331930078';
```

ouput:

```
'1 row updated'
```

**non-working** updates:

1.

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = :dn;
```

2. 

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = cast(:dn as varchar2(13));
```

output:

```
'0 rows updated'
```

Don't know what else can I do to force the value being parsed as a string.

SQL Developer version 4.1.3.20

Comment: There is no need to cast anything, your query should be: update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = :dn;

Comment: Turns out it doesn't work like that (which was what I originally assumed)

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting, and looks like a bug. You don't actually need to cast, the value from the 'enter binds' window is a string anyway, so this works:

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = :dn;
```

when the zero-padded string 08331930078 is entered in the dialog.

The cast is not needed but ought to still work. If you run as a script instead, with a defined bind variable, then both forms do work:

```
var dn varchar2(13);
exec :dn := '08331930078';
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = :dn;
rollback;
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = cast(:dn as varchar2(13));
rollback;
```

You get `1 row updated` for both statements. Going back to running as a statement still prompts and still has the same (odd) behaviour even when the bind variable has been defined in a script in the same session.

Incidentally, when you do:

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where NUM = 08331930078;
```

what you're actually doing, as you can see form the execution plan's predicate section, is:

```
update numbers_table set IS_OK = 0 where to_number(NUM) = 8331930078;
```

which will stop any index on the `num` column being used, and may result in unexpected results - in this case, if these are e.g. UK phone numbers you probably won't have the same value with and without the leading zero, but it's something to be wary of generally.

Comment: actually the first update you posted (the one with binding variable, but without explicit cast) doesn't work on my side, either

Comment: Could it be that SQL Developer is trying to be to clever? Perhaps it is seeing all the digits and assuming the bind variable is a number. As such, it drops the leading 0. When the query runs, we get either an implicit data type conversion or you do the explicit CAST(); either way, the string has now lost the leading 0.  Just a theory...